# Using Newton Raphson for Root Finding and Parameters' Estimation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cubic root equation. I wrote matlab code using newton-raphson to find the roots. I want to do parameter estimation (tuning of this cubic root equation parameters to be able to give better prediction) using experiment data. Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Thanks for your anticipated help 
Regards,
Isa

Comment: Why not use Matlab's fminsearch function to estimate the parameters?

Comment: Thanks Victor, Z^3-(1-B)Z^2+(A-3B^2-2B)Z-(AB-B^2-B^3)=0 where A=aP/R^2T^2, B=bP/RT, b=sum(xibi) and a=sumsum(xixjaij). A and B have physical parameters to be tuned. I have written matlab code to solve this cubic equation using newton raphson with initial guess. I have experimental data so I want to incorporate optimisation of the parameters (tuning) in the equation so as to be able to predict accurately under different conditions. Please if fminsearch can do this how do I incorporate it into the code? Thanks. Isa

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be using ROOTS to find the roots of cubic polynomials, like this: roots([4 -2 3 -1]) for 4x^3 - 2x^2 +3x -1.

You can easily calculate how a root changes with respect to each coordinate. In p(x)=0, one finds that dp/da + p'(x)*dx/da = 0 for any parameter a. So if a_3 is the coefficient of x^3, one gets dx/d(a_3) = -(x^3)/p'(x). You can use this to get the gradient of the root with respect to the coefficients, and conduct a gradient descent or better method to move the roots toward targets.

Comment: My issue is this, I have this eqn Z^3-(1-B)Z^2+(A-3B^2-2B)Z-(AB-B^2-B^3)=0 where A=aP/R^2T^2, B=bP/RT, b=sum(xibi) and a=sumsum(xixjaij). A and B have physical parameters to be tuned. I have written matlab code to solve this cubic equation using newton raphson with initial guess. I have experimental data so I want to incorporate optimisation of the parameters (tuning) in the equation so as to be able to predict accurately under different conditions. Please if fminsearch can do this how do I incorporate it into the code? Thanks. Isa